# redo standard product tabs to accordion

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, tabs, styles

how to make a accordion from standard horizontal tabs as shown in the picture

I looked at how to make tabs from simple blocks using the magento 2 widget but it worked out for me to apply this to a tab products

hope you help

[image]

Comment: is there any sample example demo links?

Comment: @jafarpinjar what?

Comment: what is the requirement, how it should look like? is there any demo link?

Comment: @jafarpinijar no :( only what is in the picture. but, it should work like this, now it’s just open blocks, but you need them to be under each other and when pressed open down like an accordion

Comment: Is there any dev link? so that i can look into it, or its in local?

Comment: @jafarpinijar i don’t understand what you mean, I have locally running standard magento 2.3

Comment: I need to see how its working now, what is the exact requirement, Not understanding from the picture..

Comment: @jafarpinijar I don’t have hosting with a developed project, I just want to understand how to do it, what if I click on a tab - it turned down along with the content

Comment: Now after clicking the tab, is the content loading or not?

Comment: @jafarpinijar yes

Comment: so what is the issue here, I'm sorry still not cleared

Comment: @jafarpinijar i do not understand how to add this functionality to standard tabs magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by just modifying your css

```
.product.data.items {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
}
.product.data.items > .item.title {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
.product.data.items > .item.title > .switch {
    display: block;
}
.product.data.items > .item.content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.product.data.items > .item.content::after {
    clear: both;
}
.product.data.items > .item.content.active {
    display: block;
}
.product.data.items > .item.title > .switch {
    border-color: #d1d1d1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.item.content[aria-hidden="true"] {
    display: none;
}

.product.data.items > .item.content {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.product.data.items > .item.active.title{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

If you want sliding animation, let me know

Comment: thanks for saving once again)

Comment: slide animation for tabs?

Comment: Like sliding....But need to work in jQuery

Comment: if it’s not difficult for you to give an example of smooth animation for opening tabs, then I will be very grateful

Comment: Will try and let you know later...I'm little busy with my task